# Selectize control and the TAB key

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

Is there a way to use the TAB key to select the value in a selectize dropdown and then move onto the next control?  What I'm noticing is that when I start to type out a value contained in a selectize dropdown and then press the TAB key, the selected value "disappears."  In order for the selected value to "stick," I have to press the Enter key first.  Is there a way to "select" a value using the keyboard with just the TAB key and not having to press Enter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you initialize selectize you can set selectOnTab to True.

```
$('#myControl').selectize({
  ...
  selectOnTab: true,
  ...
});
```

check the [docs](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) for more options.

Comment: That worked!  Though I had to put it in the config section of the control's controller (we are using custom controls):      controller: function($scope) {
     $scope.myConfig = {
      valueField: 'Code',
      labelField: 'Description',
      searchField: 'Description',
      selectOnTab: true,
      onInitialize: function(selectize) {
       
       
      },
      maxItems: 1
     };
    },